# Lazyload with a Bitmap Array

Tags: android

So my app lists all the files and folders in a given Dropbox folder.  They are listed in a custom ListView using an adapter.

Currently I use drawables for the image and folder icons.  I loop through the Dropbox folder structure and add the needed drawable to a Bitmap array.  This is done in an Async Task (`doInBackground`).

I then call the Adapter in the `PostExecute` like this :

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, pix, paths);
 lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This then shows all the files and images (with default drawable icons) in the ListView.

The next step I want to do is start loading the thumbnails from dropbox. 
So for every image in the List, I want to replace the drawable with a thumbnail retreived from dropbox.
Again this should be done in an Async task so the user can still scroll through the listview.

With dropbox, you can load thumbails like this:

```
if(fileInfo.thumbExists)
                        {
                           file = fileSystem.openThumbnail(fileInfo.path, ThumbSize.XS, ThumbFormat.PNG);

                            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(file.getReadStream());
                            thumbs.add(image);
                            file.close();
                        }
```

In the code above, `thumbs` is a Bitmap Array.

I was planning on using Universal Image Loader or Picasso.  But you cannot pass in a Bitmap Array into either of those. It has to be a URL or URI.

How can I achieve this?  I'm guessing I need another async task, but I'm not sure how to update my adapter.

**Considerations:**

- I don't want to wait until all thumbnails are downloaded before
  starting to display them
- Are there memory considerations if there are lots of thumbails?
- Can you only display thumnails in the Visibile    part of the
  listview, and start loading more when they scroll?

Remember - I am using an array of Bitmaps, I don't have any URLS.  Would I be best saving each Bitmap to the sd card and then using UIL or Picasso to load using the URI?  But how would you know which images went to which position in the ListView?

SO the steps in my code would ideally be:

-Load the Listview with the files and folders with dummy images (already doing this!)

-Get the thumbnails from the decodeStream and load into the Bitmap Array

-Load the thumbnails into the correct position into the ListView

Comment: could you plz share your updated code stuff for displaying list of images of dropbox folder ,actually i faces same problem  . -@user3437721 ?

Answer (score 0):

For each row of the list view, run a separate thread to download and show the thumbnail image.
I guess, you can avoid the use of a bitmap array and directly feed the downloaded image to the list view row.

I) Modify your getView() call back of the adapter like the one below:

ImageView thumbnail=Container.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail)
loadImageInBackground(thumbnail,URL).execute();

II) loadImageInBackground will be a class that implements AsyncTask

a) data members: ImageView thumbnail,String URL

b) Constructor: Initialize these data members with instances passed.

c) onPostExecute: Set a dummy image to the thumbnail here, that will appear until the required image is downloaded.You can even set an animating image here to give it a better feel.

d) doInBackground:

```
                mUrl = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();   
                conn.setDoInput(true);   
                conn.connect();     
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
                is.close();

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {       
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
```

e) onPostExecute: associate the this.thumbnail to this.bmImg.

This way for each row  of your list view an object of loadImageInBackground class will be initialized and will download the image from URL and set it to the image View container of the corresponding row.

The images will be displayed on the Thumbnail as soon as they are downloaded. There will be no Blocking, I mean, the user can interact with the app even when the images are being downloaded.
If you have implemented a lazy loading methodology, then this approach will not cause any outOfMemory exceptions in any case.And also, new images will only be downloaded when the user scrolls.
Point II.c provides for setting loading animation/image on the thumbnail until the actual image has been downloaded.

Comment: I already have an adapter in which I am loading the dummy thumbnail.  Do i need to create a new adapter with a different getView method? or can I use the same one?  Also - I don't have any URLS, there is no way to get the URL of the image thumbnail

Comment: Just update the existing adapter to include features as mentioned above or better off, create a new adapter from scratch. You can replace the doInBackground code with the one that you used to fetch image. The code snippet mentioned in the question, can be used as a replacement of suggested doInBackground block.

Comment: but since my Custom Adapter accepts a Bitmap Array as well as a String arraylist, when I update my adapter by creating a new one, I don't want to pass in the String list again? I guess I could though?  Can you write a method inside the Custom Adapter to update the Bitmap only?

Comment: I'm really struggling with this.  Please have a look at my code, I do not have any access to the image urls.  My only option is to open the online file and decode the stream to a bitmap.  I will have to do this one byy one. I just want to load these image into (my already populated) custom listview and replace the dummy images I preloaded.

Comment: How about replacing the code in doInBackground, that I posted, with the code that you are using to load thumbNail from dropBox. I think this will work because both ultimately inflates a bitmap object. Please post your feedback.

Comment: OK I'll try it, I'm just worried about Our of memory exceptions if there are lots of thumbails

Comment: There is no chance of outOfMemory Exception because we are using only one bitmap object to decode stream to bitmap, then adding this bitmap to image view. On Next iteration we **Reuse** this bitmap again as this is a Globally declared and it is **NOT** a private data member of the function.